# Angular Cli Cusom ng generate behaviour

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli, customization, directory

#### I'd like to change file structure of new components when

- From the command line I type `ng generate component pippo`

#### Observed behavior

```
create src/app/pippo/pippo.component.html (24 bytes)
create src/app/pippo/pippo.component.spec.ts (621 bytes)
create src/app/pippo/pippo.component.ts (266 bytes)
create src/app/pippo/pippo.component.scss (0 bytes)
```

#### Desired behavior

```
create src/app/components/pippo/tpl/pippo.component.html (24 bytes)
create src/app/components/pippo/ts/pippo.component.spec.ts (621 bytes)
create src/app/components/pippo/ts/pippo.component.ts (266 bytes)
create src/app/components/pippo/scss/pippo.component.scss (0 bytes)
```

#### Explanation

1. Select custom folder to deploy component, rather than using always the **app** folder
2. Separate templates, from scss, from ts as I may need more files per type

Is it possibile?
It would be also ok for me to create a custom task with npm "*fs*"

**BAT SOLUTION**

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
ECHO #################################
ECHO #################################
ECHO NG COMPONENT CREATOR BY TONY SAMPERI
ECHO #################################
ECHO #################################

set folderStatus=N
set folderName=newComponent
set sourcePath=%cd%\src\app\components
cd %sourcePath%
echo sourcePath is %sourcePath%

call :getFolderName
IF "!folderStatus!" == "C" call :createStructure
IF "!folderStatus!" == "N" call :failedWarning

PAUSE
endlocal
EXIT /B

:getFolderName
echo Component name?
set /P folderName=
IF exist %folderName% (
    echo Directory %folderName% already exists!
    goto :getFolderName
) ELSE (
    mkdir %folderName%
    set folderStatus=C
)
EXIT /B

:createStructure
cd %folderName%
echo Moved to %sourcePath%\%folderName%

mkdir ts
cd ts
type NUL > %folderName%.component.ts
cd ..
mkdir scss
cd scss
type NUL > %folderName%.component.scss
cd ..
mkdir tpl
cd tpl
type NUL > %folderName%.component.html
cd ..
echo DONE.
```

Comment: When we where seperating the componenents we would use `ng g c components/<component-type>/<component-name>` So if where making a page it would be `ng g c components/pages/home` if that helps

Comment: mm not much. I don't want to write the path every time. Also I need to separate htmls from ts's and scss's

Comment: From what I've read around because I looked for something like this a while back and the only way I found was the way I've said. I didn't wanna type it out everytime too

Comment: If separating by type is enough for you you could write your own commands in *package.json* under the **scripts** property. 
So for example `buildLayoutComponent: ng g c layouts/$name` but honestly I don't know how to read dynamically $name from the command

Comment: Yeah true you could which would make it faster but like You have said i don't even know a way to do that too. When i end up doing it i just press the up key and change the last bit so I'm not always typing it all out. But i do i have ZSH set up